# How to work without memory limit in android jni?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, sdl-2

Sorry for my bad english. I am developing a small client program for my smart home system. I want to use SDL2, because it runs Android, OS X, iOS, Windows, Linux.. Multiplatform is important for me, i can't write programs in java, so can't write android apps, only with jni and C++, but if the memory usage will be over 24 mb the app exits with out of memory error. What can i do in this case?

Comment: Check this: http://blog.javia.org/how-to-work-around-androids-24-mb-memory-limit/